# Should Magento sitemap contain empty categories?

Tags: magento, seo

From SEO point of view, isn't it dangerous to give out a page without any practical value? If you advertise to have content for a particular category, but you actually don't, wouldn't that make the poeple who clicked on the link to just move along? 
More importantly, would the empty category not make guys working at Google mark your website as spammy? Cause you have 100 categories in your sitemap, and only 10 actually contain products?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using them for content or other presentation you should hide/disable categories that are empty until you have products in them.

Comment: ERP regulates whether there are products in a category.. today there might be some, tomorrow not.. it would be cumbersome to program a functionality that would do the check and disable the cat if there are no products. It's much easier to rewrite sitemap module to exclude empty categories. 
That however doesn't answer the original question - is it a problem at all, to have empty categories show up in sitemap.

Comment: Removing categories from the sitemap does not solve your problem at all.  Google still crawls your site, so if links to these categories exist, and they are not rel=nofollow then google will still find the empty categories.  Either way, it is bad from an SEO perspective to have indexed pages without unique content.

Comment: I think that by default, Magento hides empty categories from navigation, therefore only place it appears in is sitemap